# Why does sscanf perform strangely here?

Tags: matlab, scanf

I am using `sscanf` in `Matlab` and it works fine unless a specific combination of characters are used:

```
sscanf('2015.10.07-00:07:01', '%i.%i.%i-%i:%i:%i')
```

return the array

```
ans =

        2015
          10
           7
           0
           7
           1
```

but

```
sscanf('2015.10.07-00:08:01', '%i.%i.%i-%i:%i:%i')
```

returns

```
ans =

        2015
          10
           7
           0
           0
```

Note that changing `07` and/or `08` to `01` through `02` also returns what I would expect. Is this coincidence and I am actually reading the line wrong or is there something weird going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html), it appears it was being read as hex. I needed to use `%d` rather than `%i` to force base 10 interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I try this

```
sscanf('2015.10.08-00:07:01', '%i.%i.%i-%i:%i:%i')
```

return

```
2015
10
0
```

According to the documentation on [sscanf](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html), it is read as base 8 (00-07), because intial value is 0. I think this causes error since 08 is read in as 0 and it stops reading the rest of the string.